# How Can I render Two-dimensions-Array in JSX (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I am coding Two-dimensions-Array in ReactNative.

Single-Array is successful in JSX.
But I do not get how to use Two-dimensions-Array in JSX.
Can we use Two-dimensions-Array in JSX ?

Rendering is successful

```js
<View>
  {myDoubleArray.map(loop => {
    return <Text>{loop}</Text>;
  })}
</View>
```

Rendering is **nothing** (my question)

```js
<View>
  {myDoubleArray.map(loop => {
    loop.map(elm => {
      return <Text>{elm}</Text>;
    });
  })}
</View>
```

myDoubleArray is Two-dimensions-Array like this.

```js
const myDoubleArray = new Array(5).fill(null);
for (let y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
  myDoubleArray[y] = new Array(3);
  for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    myDoubleArray[y][x] = y + ' : ' + x;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to return the inner map. `loop.map(elm => {` should be `loop.map(elm => return {` or remove the curly braces.

Comment: What's the syntax error? Also, please don't post code in comments.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake and thank your advices.

When I repalced from `loop.map(elm => {` to `loop.map(elm => return {`,
I got Unexpected token of Syntax Error in point of `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return a value from the outer map function. So, the product of it is an array of **undefined**s.
You just need a **return** statement:

```
<View>
  {myDoubleArray.map(loop => {
    return loop.map(elm => {
      return <Text>{elm}</Text>;
    });
  })}
</View>
```

Comment: This code renderd successfuly ! Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code you don't return anything and you forgot to assign a key I used the indexes it's not great but I don't know the contents of your array.

```
<View>
  {myDoubleArray.map((loop, indexA) => 
    loop.map((elm, indexB) => (
      <Text key={`${indexA}_${indexB}`}>{elm}</Text>
    ))
  )}
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointin out.  Exactly. I deliberately omited indexes to simplify code. But it become problematic code. I will be careful from next time.